# Plotting various amount of columns in Excel

Tags: python, excel, plot

I have an Excel file with several columns.
From this columns I want to plot columns which have a name like this:
IVOF_1_H, IVOF_1_L, IVOF_2_H, IVOF_2_L,...those columns will be on y axis. For the x axis the column will always be the same

I do not know how many of those columns I have in the file. I only know that the number is increasing. Is there any possibility to check how many of those IVOF columns I have and plot them.

In general, there is a limitation of those IVOF columns and I don't mind to set up my script in a way that all of those columns got plotted (if they are existing), but then I don't know how to avoid the code to crash if one of those columns is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data frame by its column name:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
df = df.filter(regex=("IVOF.*"))
#plot the first row
df.iloc[0].plot(kind="bar")
#plot all rows
df.plot(kind="bar")
```

simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df =  pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,4,4],[4,3,3],[5,9,1]]),columns=['A','B1','B2'])
df = df.filter(regex=("B.*"))
df.plot(kind="bar")
```

The result:

[image]